# Plugin 'com.android.application' not found in build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to build my Android project in Android Studio, but I keep getting the following error message in my build.gradle file:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources
```

I have tried running the build with the "--info" and "--debug" options, but I'm not getting any more useful information. I have also tried running the build with the "--scan" option to get more insights, but that didn't help either.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem? I have checked that the version of the Android Gradle plugin is up-to-date, but I'm still getting this error. What else could be causing this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I encountered the error message `Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources` in my `build.gradle` file, I tried running the build with the "--info" and "--debug" options to get more log output, but this didn't provide any useful information.

I also tried running the build with the "--scan" option to get more insights into the issue, but that didn't help either. I checked that the version of the Android Gradle plugin was up-to-date and made sure that all the necessary dependencies were included in the build file.

I expected the build to run successfully and generate an APK file for my Android application. However, the build failed with the error message mentioned above.

I am now seeking help from the Stack Overflow community to understand what could be causing this issue and find a solution.

Comment: Can you add you gradle file?

Comment: Please, share your gradle file as an app level and root level.